# Cannot resolve symbol TestUtil in android

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm trying to test Room database. my code is as below but TestUtill is red.

```
 @Test
public void writeUserAndReadInList() throws Exception {
    UserRequest user = TestUtil.createUser(3);
    user.setFullname("george");
    mUserDao.insertAll(user);
    List<UserRequest> byName = mUserDao.findByName("george");
    assertThat(byName.get(0), equalTo(user));
}
```

also I have an incompatible error message in line `List<UserRequest> byName = mUserDao.findByName("george");`, saying it required java.util.list found mypackagename.RequestUser

Answer (score 1):

You need to create that `TestUtil` class.

Here is the one in Kotlin: [TestUtil](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/test-common/java/com/android/example/github/util/TestUtil.kt)

Comment: what should I define inside that class? where is the one for Android :D

Comment: This is for android for sure but in kotlin not java. The tutorial that you follow should provide the link to the Java one, if not it is not difficult to convert it to Java since it is a small class.